# How to use jvectormap in React+webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jvectormap

[jvertormap](http://jvectormap.com/) is a library + database of countries borders. It is very convenient to show geo distribution of visitors.

I was using it with angular, but now we are moving to React and I wonder if there is a simple way to use it with React or even use it without jquery?

Problem is that I want to leave in webpack ecosystem, use package.json and import mechanism.